# What is my obsolete Facebook API call?

Tags: javascript, api, facebook-javascript-sdk, obsolete

I recently got a notice that I'm using one or more obsolete calls which will impact the website shortly.  The problem is that I can't find any useful documentation to determine which call is obsolete and every call that I'm making seems to still be ok.

Can anybody tell me which one of these calls is obsolete?

```
FB.init
FB.Event.subscribe  // auth.login, auth.logout
FB.getLoginStatus
FB.api
FB.login
FB.logout
```

> As announced in the Facebook Developer blog, Facebook is in the
>   process of removing methods from the Javascript SDK that are not
>   officially supported. Your app "MY APP" (MY APP NUMBER) has been
>   identified as using such methods, and we are informing you about this
>   now so that you can make the necessary changes to avoid your
>   application being affected when we first make these methods into empty
>   stubs, and subsequently when we remove them.

Thanks!
Brett

Comment: I'm assuming `FB.logo` is supposed to be `FB.logout`? [As far as I can see](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/) none of these are "obsolete"?

Comment: Your question is as vague as the "notice" you got.  Could you please tell us a bit more about who sent it, and exactly what they say???

Comment: I've added their notice and fixed FB.logout

Comment: @Brett Miller: thanx for the update.  The links I gave below are still probably your best bets.  Here's the ["Facebook Developer Blog"](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/archive#2012).  You're interested in the ["Operation Developer Love"](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/07/11/platform-updates--operation-developer-love/) entries.  'Hope that helps.

Comment: I got the same email from Facebook too, but no idea which method is going to be deprecated. I used FB.init, FB.api, FB.getLoginStatus and FB.Event.subscribe

Answer (score 1):

Q: Have you looked here:

- http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/oldjavascript/

  or here:
- http://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/

Q: Could you tell us exactly what this "notice" said?

ADDENDUM:

- ["Facebook Developer Blog"](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/archive#2012)
- You're interested in the ["Operation Developer Love"](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/07/11/platform-updates--operation-developer-love/) entries.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry for the vagueness of this email, but I can assure you, if these are the methods you use, then you are safe.

Common reasons for getting this email are

- using a third-party component that use such a method (many flash SDK's do this)
- users browsing your site with an extension that use such a method
- someone copy-pasting code from you, inheriting your appId
- someone having a typo in their appId, so that it matches yours

Answer (score -1):

I think... are you sure what App ID do you have? (completed application)
you can't use this App ID on the other App. check it:  https://developers.facebook.com/apps